# Inequality with maximum

Tags: inequality

This should be simple, but I can't figure it out.
In an ordered field, does this hold? :

$$ \max\{ a,b\} - \max\{ c,d\} \le \max \{a-c,b-d\} $$

If not, does this hold? :

$$ |\max\{ a,b\} - \max\{ c,d\}| \le |\max \{a-c,b-d\}| $$

Edit:
Haskell's quickcheck says the first property holds (and by extension the second):

```
prop1 :: Double -> Double -> Double -> Double -> Bool
prop1 a b c d = (max a b - max c d) <= (max (a-c) (b-d))

*Main Test.QuickCheck> quickCheck prop1 
+++ OK, passed 100 tests.
quickCheckWith stdArgs { maxSuccess = 100000 } prop1
+++ OK, passed 100000 tests.
```

I would still like to see a proof, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separating it into cases will help.

Let $S=\max\{a-c,b-d\}-\max\{a,b\}+\max\{c,d\}$.

- If $a\ge b,c\ge d,a-c\ge b-d$, then $S=a-c-a+c=0$.
- If $a\ge b,c\ge d,a-c\lt b-d$, then $S=b-d-a+c=(b-d)-(a-c)\gt 0$.
- If $a\ge b,c\lt d$, then $a-c\ge b-d$ and $S=a-c-a+d=d-c\gt 0$.
- If $a\lt b,c\ge d$, then $a-c\lt b-d$ and $S=b-d-b+c=c-d\ge 0$.
- If $a\lt b,c\lt d,a-c\ge b-d$, then $S=a-c-b+d=(a-c)-(b-d)\gt 0$.
- If $a\lt b,c\lt d,a-c\lt b-d$, then $S=b-d-b+d=0$.

Hence, $$S\ge 0\iff \max\{a,b\}-\max\{c,d\}\le \max\{a-c,b-d\}$$ always holds.